# Accessing object in perform_create when using many=true

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How can I get object in `perform_create()` when I use `kwargs['many'] = True`?

I get this error message:

> Serializers with many=True do not support multiple update by default,
>   only multiple create. For updates it is unclear how to deal with
>   insertions and deletions. If you need to support multiple update, use
>   a `ListSerializer` class and override `.update()` so you can specify
>   the behavior exactly.

```
class CreateUserApiView(CreateAPIView):
    model = User
    ...
    serializer_class = CreateRequesterSerializer

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ if an array is passed, set serializer to many """
        if isinstance(kwargs.get('data', {}), list):
            kwargs['many'] = True
        return super(CreateUserApiView, self).get_serializer(*args, **kwargs)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        obj = serializer.save(
            ...,
            created_by=self.request.user)
        obj.send_invitation()
```

Comment: You only get this error if you call the 'update' method but I don't see if you are doing such, can you share the serializer code too?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in serializer. Basically your serializer knows how to create one object, but you are asking him to create many. In DRF3 this many objects creation should be implemented manually.

So basically you need to rewrite your serializer: inherit it from `ListSerializer` (because you are expecting many objects input) and implement `update` method.